# Is the following set open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$$S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\mid x^2 - y^2 < 1 \}$$
According to my geometry if we define $r$ as follows it should work, however I am having hard ideas proving it.

Consider $z \in S$ and consider $B(z,r)$ where $r := \min(|z|, 1 - |z|,|z| - |q|)$, where $|q|$ is the smallest norm that satisfies the following properties:
$$
q = x + ix, \text{where $(|q| < 1)$ & $(|q| < |z|)$}
$$
According to my geometrical picture this should work, but having alot of troubles proving it.

How I got this if we draw a ball centered at $0$ in $\mathbb R^2$ with radius $1$ we find that our set $S$ is actually to the left of $x = y$ so we find the following $r$, however I can't get the rigour.

Comment: I think you wanted to say $S= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 - y^2 < 1 \}$

Comment: yeah your correct !

Comment: You're* :) And for the $\mathbb R$ you can write \mathbb R

Comment: @ThePortakal $\Bbb R$ surely fits, but Rudin simply uses $R$ in his book ;)

Comment: Hey @Vim thanks, I didn't know that :) Every time I see a $R$, I cannot stop thinking of a ring :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have deleted my first answer which is based on geometrical intuition but without rigourous logic. Now this new version is more rigourously organized.

Suppose the point $A,B,C$ are located above the $x$-axis (the other cases follow similarly). We have to show that every point $A(x_0,y_0)$ such that $x_0^2-y_0^2=r^2<1$ is an interior point to the set defined by $x^2-y^2<1$.

Let $H:x^2-y^2=1$ and $H_r:x^2-y^2=r^2<1$ be the two hyperbolas. First, I claim that $1<|k_A|<+\infty$ where $k_A$ denotes the tangent at $A\in H_r$. Recall that the equation of the tangent line is $x_0x-y_0y=r^2$ and hence $$|k_A|=|x_0/y_0|=|\frac{\sqrt{y_0^2+r^2}}{y_0}|=\sqrt{1+\frac{r^2}{y_0^2}}\in(1,+\infty)$$
Similarly, this is also true for $|k_B|$ and $|k_C|$ (they denote tangents at $B,C \in H$, respectively). 
[image]
Now I am able to find a point $C\in H$ s.t. $|k_C|>|k_A|$, because $|k_A|$ is bounded, and $|k_C|$ can tend to infinity as $C$ tends to $(1,0)$, therefore such a $C$ must exist. Also, I am able to find a point $B\in H$ s.t. $|k_B|<|k_A|$, because $|k_A|>1$, I can always find a $\kappa$ s.t. $|k_A|>\kappa>1$, moreover $|k_B|\to1^+$ as $x_B\to+\infty$ and $|k_B|$ depends continuously on $x_B\in(1,+\infty)$, hence $|k_B|$ must hit $\kappa<|k_A|$ at some point.

Clearly $1<x_C<x_B<+\infty$ and $|k_B|<|k_A|<|k_C|$. Let 
$$|k(x)|=\sqrt{1+\frac1{y^2(x)}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2-1}}$$
 be the tangent at the point $(x,y_x)\in H$. It is easy to check that $|k(x)|\in\mathscr C^1(1,+\infty)$ and hence $|k(x)|\in\mathscr C^1[x_C,x_B]$. By Lagrange mean value theorem, there must exist some point $D\in H$ between $B$ and $C$ s.t. $|k_D|=|k_A|$ ($k_D=k_A$ for this case).

Thus $L_A$ and $L_D$ are parallel and of course they don't overlap (since $A\ne D$). Let $d$ be the distance between them, then clearly $B_d(A)$ does not intersect the area $x^2-y^2\ge 1$ and hence $A$ is interior to the area defined by $x^2-y^2<1$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Very very nice !

Comment: @Dude thank u. Well there were several typos, now fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$. Then $S = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid f(x,y) < 1\} = f^{-1}(-\infty,1)$. Now what do you know about $(-\infty,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$, and what do you know about preimages of open sets under continuous functions?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by  first principle, that is directly verifying the defining condition:  Take a point $P=(a,b)\in S$. Now find $\lambda>0$ such that the point $Q=(\lambda a,\lambda b)$ is on the circle of radius 1 centred at origin. Then $Q$ will be the closest point to $P$ lying on that circle.

Now take a circle of radius less than half this distance centred at $P$. This circle will lie completely lie inside $S$, thereby proving the requirement for  being an open set.

EDIT: There is a problem in my answer. The part about how to find the closest point $Q$ from $P$ lying on the circle should be changed to lying on the hyperbola $x^2-y^1=1$. It is not clear there is an easy geometric procedure for that. But otherwise the answer is ok.